# How to Insert User(Client Side) Entry By Default?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have

Admin Side and Client-Side

and I have only one table for admin login and client login see the Reference Image

When User Login Then Insert an Entry as a User?

Reference:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqEu0.jpg

I want to ex:

Database Entry

UserType: User
EmailId:  benssok@gmail.com
Password: bens1234
FirstName: nicks
LastName: andrew

Code:

c#
Registation ClientSide:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstname = txtFirstName.Text;
    string lastname = txtLastName.Text;
    string emailid = txtEmailId.Text;
    string password = txtclientpassword.Text;
    ClientLogin_Click(firstname, lastname, emailid, password);
}`enter code here`

void ClientLogin_Click(string firstname,string lastname,string emailid,string Password)
{
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ToString();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn);

    string Insertquery = "Insert into tbladminclient(FirstName,LastName,EmailId,Password) values(@FirstName,@LastName,@EmailId,@Password)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Insertquery, cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", emailid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);

    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        int validateOperation = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (validateOperation > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("successfully Registration");
            Response.Redirect("ClientLogin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Not successfully Registration");
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        Response.Write("error");
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

AdminLogin Page   //Problem Occured when Same Login(AdminSide) and sameLogin(ClientSide) what the differance? How to resolve this problem ? How to Identify User(clientside) and admin(adminside)Login??

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string userName = txtEmailId.Text;
            string Password = txtUserPassword.Text;
            Login_Click(userName, Password);
        }

        void Login_Click(string emailid, string Password)
        {
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ToString();
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbladminclient where EmailId=@EmailId and Password=@Password", cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", emailid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //data read from the database 

            if (dr.HasRows == true)   //HasRows means one or more row read from the database
            {
                Response.Write("successfully Login");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Not successfully Login");
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
```

problem is when Same `Login(AdminSide)` and `sameLogin(ClientSide)` what the differance? How to resolve this problem ? How to Identify User(clientside) and admin(adminside)Login??

Comment: @xdtTransform I think It is not a duplicate question I insert data successfully what is an issue? the issue is I want the when the user Insert a record in client-side then Automatically User(UserType) Entry Inserted In the database.

Comment: Two options 1) either set a default value for that field in the SQL CREATE TABLE definition, or 2) hard-code it into the C# code e.g. `string Insertquery = "Insert into tbladminclient(UserType, FirstName,LastName,EmailId,Password) values(@UserTyppe, @FirstName,@LastName,@EmailId,@Password)"; ... cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserType", "user");`

Comment: P.S. you really ought to hash and salt your passwords. Plain-text passwords are a security risk.

Comment: P.P.S. `ClientLogin_Click` ..."Login" is a terrible name for a method which carries out the task of registering the user. Logging in is a separate task. Please use meaningful names for variables, classes, methods etc. Otherwise you will just confuse yourself and others when you come to try and debug or update the code later.

Comment: P.P.P.S. Speaking of classes, it would be better practice (and lead to more maintainable code) to use a class to pass the details of your user from one method to another, instead of separate parameters for each field.

Comment: @ADyson Ok I following the NamingConversation next time

Comment: you mean "naming convention" I think, not conversation :-)

Comment: @ADyson naming convention sorry for this I think my question is understood u.

Comment: No problem. Did you try either of my suggestions then? (I mean from my first comment)

Comment: @ADyson Now my problem is the same login credentials enter in admin side then login successfully??

Comment: basically you need to check the table to ensure the user has the correct UserType to allow them access to that area. So...when you are receiving the login details from the admin side's login page, don't just check the username and password is valid, check that the usertype is "admin" as well.

Comment: Or, here's a better idea: Just have one single login page for the whole app, and when the user logs in, get their usertype from the table and store it in the Session. Then whenever they visit an "admin" page, check the session value before displaying the page (you would need to be doing that anyway in actual fact, otherwise each individual page has no way to know what kind of user is visiting). This is the basic beginnings of a full role-based-access system.

Comment: @ADyson I solve my question today

Comment: That's great. Is it something you can add as an answer here, then other people can benefit from it?

Comment: @ADyson ok I put my answer and its work perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First when user(client-side) registration form fill up go to database and execute query

```
ALTER TABLE [tbladminclient]
ADD CONSTRAINT df_UserType
DEFAULT 'User' FOR UserType; //whenever you insert then Bydefault Entry is User:
```

how to identify user is client or admin

Code:
User LogIn

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string emailid = txtemailId.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;

    Client_Login(emailid,password);
}

void Client_Login(string emailid,string password)
{
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ToString();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbladminclient where EmailId=@EmailId and Password=@Password", cn);
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", emailid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //data read from the database 

    if (dr.HasRows == true)//HasRows means one or more row read from the database
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr["UserType"].ToString() == "User")
            {
                Response.Write("successfully Client Login");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Not successfully Client Login");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Not Found");
    }

    cn.Close();
}
```

Admin LogIn

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = txtEmailId.Text;
    string Password = txtUserPassword.Text;
    Login_Click(userName, Password);
}

void Login_Click(string emailid, string Password/*string UserType*/)
{
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ToString();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbladminclient where EmailId=@EmailId and Password=@Password", cn);

    cn.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", emailid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //data read from the database 

    if (dr.HasRows == true)//HasRows means one or more row read from the database
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr["UserType"].ToString() == "admin")
            {
                Response.Write("Successfully Admin Login");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Not successfully Admin Login");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Not Found");
    }
    cn.Close();
}
```